# App not printing text after connecting to bluetooth device (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-bluetooth

I'm currently trying to make an app that connects to a bluetooth device and once done prints out the

I'm having the problem once it connects it doesn't print out the services and instead prints out "while delegate is either nil or does not implement peripheral:didDiscoverServices:". But the problem is that I do have didDiscoverServices.

Here is my viewcontroller

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

let rowerServiceCBUUID = CBUUID(string: "CE060000-43E5-11E4-916C-0800200C9A66")

class HRMViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var heartRateLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var bodySensorLocationLabel: UILabel!
  var centralManager: CBCentralManager!
  var pmPeripheral: CBPeripheral!
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    // Make the digits monospaces to avoid shifting when the numbers change
    heartRateLabel.font = UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFont(ofSize: heartRateLabel.font!.pointSize, weight: .regular)
  }

  func onHeartRateReceived(_ heartRate: Int) {
    heartRateLabel.text = String(heartRate)
    print("BPM: \(heartRate)")
  }
}
extension HRMViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
  func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
    case .unknown:
      print("central.state is .unknown")
    case .resetting:
      print("central.state is .resetting")
    case .unsupported:
      print("central.state is .unsupported")
    case .unauthorized:
      print("central.state is .unauthorized")
    case .poweredOff:
      print("central.state is .poweredOff")
    case .poweredOn:
      print("central.state is .poweredOn")
      centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [rowerServiceCBUUID])
    @unknown default: break

    }
  }

  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
    pmPeripheral = peripheral
    centralManager.stopScan()
    centralManager.connect(pmPeripheral!)
  }
  func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected!")
    pmPeripheral.discoverServices(nil)
  }
}
extension HRMViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate {
  func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?) {
    guard let services = peripheral.services else { return }

    for service in services {
      print(service)
      pmPeripheral.delegate = self
    }
  }
}
```

Does anyone know what I should do? Thanks.

Comment: You haven't assigned `self` to`peripheral.delegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you set your central manager's delegate, you have not set the *peripheral's* delegate. In `centralManager(_,didDiscover,advertisementData)`, add:

```
pmPeripheral.delegate = self
```

That should resolve your warning and the delegate method will be called.